# Rails deploy on heroku fails with NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.1"], nil]]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

After update to rails 6. My rails application works in localhost, but failed to be deployed on heroku. 
With NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.1"], nil]].
 Here is the heroku logs

```
    Bundle completed (202.90s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/config/application.rb:15)
       Sending event 8d83a3662d87418682154b98aecd586c to Sentry
       Unable to record event with remote Sentry server (Raven::Error - the server responded with status 429 Error in headers is: Creation of this event was denied due to rate limiting):
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/transports/http.rb:34:in `rescue in send_event'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/transports/http.rb:16:in `send_event'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/client.rb:43:in `send_event'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/instance.rb:81:in `send_event'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/instance.rb:126:in `capture_type'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `capture_exception'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.12.2/lib/raven/integrations/rake.rb:9:in `display_error_message'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:195:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:185:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Failed to submit event: NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.1"], nil]]
       rake aborted!
       NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["detected unsupported rails version 6.0.1"], nil]]
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:52:in `const_get'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:52:in `load_framework_class'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:32:in `new_instance'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/new_relic/control/class_methods.rb:13:in `instance'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-5.7.0.350/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_beaa9fdc79751f9cff81884a8400ec45/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: You should ask mr. https://twitter.com/schneems to update settings on heroku.

Comment: I actually found that removing gem 'newrelic_rpm' fixes a problem. But need another solution. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade, fork&patch or temporary disable new_relic gem.

Currently, new_relic 7.2 supports up to rails 6.

So you could be encountering this error again with Rails 7 soon

```
NameError: wrong constant name [[:error, ["Detected unsupported Rails version 7.0.0.alpha2"], nil]]
```

Change this line to support rails 7

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/blob/7.2.0/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/default_source.rb#L130

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/blob/7.2.0/lib/new_relic/agent/configuration/default_source.rb#L124-L135